# Returning a PDOException when trying to connect to MySQL Database

Tags: php

I am returning a PDOException saying I could not connect to the server and I cannot figure out why... I am Following PHPAccademy's guide on YouTube.

This is the code used to define the connection parameters

```
'db' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => '107.170.30.229',
        'name' => 'bsa',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'password',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
        'prefix' => ''
    ],
```

This is the code that is used to connect to the database

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver' => $app->config->get('db.driver'),
    'host' => $app->config->get('db.host'),
    'database' => $app->config->get('db.name'),
    'username' => $app->config->get('db.username'),
    'password' => $app->config->get('db.password'),
    'charset' => $app->config->get('db.charset'),
    'collation' => $app->config->get('db.collation'),
    'prefix' => $app->config->get('db.prefix'),
]);

$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: 1) Post the full error / exception message in your question. 2) Avoid YouTube tutorials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please **DO NOT** post any username/passwords onto SO, regardless of development or not, not everybody reading has a good heart.

Secondly, as i was able to log into your server and test this myself, it seems that you need to use **localhost** instead of defining your server IP for the host.

So please use:

```
'host' => 'localhost',
```

Instead of:

```
'host' => '107.170.30.229',
```

Comment: Can you look at my other question please?